# Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] Exception in thread

Tags: java, android

Закоммитился - нормально.
После обновления с свн, при компиляции начал получать несовсем понятный мне `exception`, причем ругается не только на `mysql-connector`, но и на другие библиотеки и проект в целом, когда как. На машине, с которой был сделан коммит - все работает.
`Exception`:

```
Information:15.06.2017 11:12 - Compilation completed with 22 errors and 0 warnings in 3 sec
Error:Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Error:Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:130)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/dexer/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.loadDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:75)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:128)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.main(AndroidDxRunner.java:294)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] ... 5 more
```

Если убрать `Pre-Dex` из настроек то получим похожий `exception`:

```
Information:15.06.2017 11:25 - Compilation completed with 22 errors and 0 warnings in 3 sec
Error:Android Dex: [carwash] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Error:Android Dex: [carwash] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error:Android Dex: [carwash] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
Error:Android Dex: [carwash] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Error:Android Dex: [carwash] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Error:Android Dex: [carwash] at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:130)
Error:Android Dex: [carwash] Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/dexer/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:Android Dex: [carwash] at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:Android Dex: [carwash] at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
Error:Android Dex: [carwash] at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
Error:Android Dex: [carwash] at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
Error:Android Dex: [carwash] at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
Error:Android Dex: [carwash] at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
Error:Android Dex: [carwash] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
Error:Android Dex: [carwash] at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:Android Dex: [carwash] at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
Error:Android Dex: [carwash] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
Error:Android Dex: [carwash] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Error:Android Dex: [carwash] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.loadDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:75)
Error:Android Dex: [carwash] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:128)
Error:Android Dex: [carwash] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.main(AndroidDxRunner.java:294)
Error:Android Dex: [carwash] ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка **"Unsupported major.minor version 52.0"**, означает, что код соответствует версии 52 (**Java 8**), но вы пытаетесь его собрать компилятором версией ниже.

Зайдите в настройки и проверьте соответствуют ли JDK и Android SDK требованиям компилируемого проекта.

В Android Studio перейдите по:

`File` > `Project Structure` > `SDK Location`

Убедитесь что стоит галочка на пункте `Use the embedded JDK`

---

Вот таблица соответствия версий на будущее:

```
Java SE 8 = 52
Java SE 7 = 51
Java SE 6.0 = 50,
Java SE 5.0 = 49
JDK 1.4 = 48
JDK 1.3 = 47
JDK 1.2 = 46
JDK 1.1 = 45
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, очень важная таблица и я о ней вроди как помню!
Может я конечно чего то не до-понимаю, т.к. это мой первый проект для робота, но все же; 
**JAVA_HOME: 1.8.0.121
Project SDK: API 19 (java version 1.8.0.121)
Project SDK: API 23 (java version 1.8.0.121)
Language Level: java 6**
если левел подымаю до 7-й  то уже вылетает:
'Error:java: javacTask: source release 1.7 requires target release 1.7'
_О 8-м левеле писать пожалуй не стану, тк робот о нем пока что еще догадывается вовсе_
И что самое смешное окружение на обеих машинах одинаковое...

Comment: @Alex , не понимаю о каком роботе идёт речь, поскольку в вопросе о нём не было ни слова. НО...JAVA_HOME может быть какой угодно. В IDE Вы можете параллельно работать с разными проектами, ориентированными на разные версии джавы.

Comment: @Alex , я опять же не знаю о чём догадывается робот, но в ошибке явно указано, что компилировать Вы должны с использованием JDK соответствующим версии 52(Java 1.8).

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, скриншот данного меню: `File` > `Project Structure` > `SDK Location` в вопросе.

Comment: @Alex , `Java 6` была выпущена аж в 2006 году, в то время как `Android` появился в 2009, про API 19 я уже молчу

Comment: Да прошу прощения Вы правы Михаил пыталось работать под 1.6, - нашел еще одну настройку, в IntelijIdea в которой заменил 1.6 на 1.8.
Но появилась новая ошибка уже типа   
`Error:Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] Failed to load dx.jar
Error:Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.dx.command.DxConsole
Error:Android Pre Dex: [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar] at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)`
и т.д. и тп
В общем спасибо. буду гуглить дальше.

Comment: @Alex, задавайте вопросы ещё. А последняя ошибка намекает на то что не может найти соответствующий класс.

Comment: я понял что не может найти класс. В принципе все проблемы решил полной переустановкой SDK. с помощью старого инсталятора **android -installer_r22.0.5-windows** и последующим апдейтом

Answer (score 0):

Михаил был прав действительно существовала проблема с настройкой 1.6 - 1.8, но даже когда я везде менял на 1.8 оно автоматом слетало или выкидывало екзепшны.

Все проблемы решил **полной переустановкой SDK**. с помощью старого инсталятора **android-installer_r22.0.5-windows** и последующим апдейтом.
PS/ По крайней мере собрал проект и запустил.